# What happens when I echo with `-e` argument?

Tags: cat, echo, ascii

As you can see, I have created `index.php` as follows:

```
$ echo -e "<?php passthru(\$_POST[1])?>\r<?php echo 'A PHP Test ';" > index.php
```

and then:

```
$ cat index.php
<?php echo 'A PHP Test ';?>
```

But:

```
$ cat -e index.php
<?php passthru($_POST[1])?>^M<?php echo 'A PHP Test ';$
```

How I can explain that?

Comment: `\r` bring cursor back to beginning of line, the `<?php ..` overwrite it. By the way there is a missing `?>`.

Comment: @Archemar is right. You most likely want to use `\n` rather than `\r`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From **man echo**

```
-e
enable interpretation of backslash escapes
If -e is in effect, the following sequences are recognized:
\r
carriage return
```

From **man cat**

```
-e
equivalent to -vE
-E, --show-ends
display $ at end of each line
-v, --show-nonprinting
use ^ and M- notation, except for LFD and TAB
```

So as I understand the `\r` expression returns the carriage, so you're echoing all after the return, that's why when you simple `cat index.php` the output is `<?php echo 'A PHP Test ';?>`.

When you `cat` using the `-e` option you're printing `^M` when there's a nonprinting statement and `$` at the very end of the line as the `-E` option do

Comment: **The** `echo` man page does not list any options. As a result, echo does not support `--` as well. The only documented problem with the echo command is that there has been a -n option in the ninth edition of UNIX and BSD. So be careful when using vendor specific "features" from a non-standard utility.